# Edit language pack Magento2

Tags: translation, magento2

I've a Magento 2 store in Italian (I've selected the language in Locale Options). Now I need to edit "Enter discount code" in the Check-out page, but I can't find the Italian translation pack. In the various i18n folders, I can only find en_US.csv.

I am new to Magento 2 so I don't really know how to do this. If I selected the Italian in the Backend, it means the package is installed, right? How do I know which one of the translation files are right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't provide Italian language pack you can install [that package](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-italian-language-pack#3-download-and-install-manually-not-recommend)

use the third method for manual install so you can edit the translation file

then clear the cache